Issue with concurrent database calls Using ZeosLib
I have a problem with a function that interacts with the database. When I call it sequentially, it works perfectly, but when I call it concurrently, it gives me an error.
Is ZeosLib not thread-safe, and how can I fix this issue? I don't want to create a new connection each time I call the function, as I'm using a single connection for all requests.
I'm using Firebird, Delphi 12, and ZeosLib 6.5.1 (alpha).
Here is the function I am using:
procedure TestFunction;
var
Query: TZEOSQuery;
begin
Query := TZEOSQuery.Create(nil);
try
Query.Connection := MyConn;

MyConn.StartTransaction;

Query.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM project';
Query.Open;

while not Query.EOF do
begin
Query.Next;
end;

MyConn.Commit;
finally
Query.Close;
Query.Free;
end;
end;


Each thread needs its own connection!

Is there any way to do this with one connection? Because if I create a new connection each time I call the function, it will create a new session in the database, which could cause a problem. I tried locking the connection and working with a single connection, but that’s not a good solution either. I don’t know why the connection is not thread-safe.

Why are you using an old pre-release version, while there are newer released (stable) versions of ZeosLib? Also, please provide a [mre], because to code as shown doesn't seem to have any concurrency. Also specify what the problem is (what errors or wrong behaviour you see). In any case, you should allocate a connection per thread, because even if ZeosLib is threadsafe, that doesn't mean your actions are (e.g. you're committing within the function, which will interfere with what another thread is doing with the same connection, e.g. it will close open cursors).

Use a connection pool to reuse already established connections
